# C# class scope confusion

Tags: c#, class, scope, partial

I currently have a main class and couple helper classes. Both classes are each in separate class files, inside 'Classes' folder (under solution explorer).

**Form1.cs**

```
public static Classes.MAIN_APP app = new Classes.MAIN_APP();
// execute function to fetch MAIN_APP's variable
app.helper_1[0].get_variable_i_want();
```

**Classes:**

```
// main_app.cs
public partial class MAIN_APP {
   public List<HELPER_CLASS_1> helper_1 = new ....

   public int VARIABLE_I_WANT_TO_ACCESS;
}

// helper_1.cs
public partial class HELPER_CLASS_1 {

   public int get_variable_i_want(){
      return VARIABLE_I_WANT_TO_ACCESS;
   }

}
```

Currently I have *VARIABLE_I_WANT_TO_ACCESS* defined in *Form1.cs* file. as *public static int*. Surprisingly if I move the helper class to *Form1.cs*, the variable becomes accessible directly.

I also tried to define *MAIN_APP* instance in *HELPER_CLASS_1*, but as far as I understood, it creates another instance of the *MAIN_APP* and I get the value of the new created instance, instead of original one.

What would be a better way to scope this? How can I access the variable I need from the sub class? Thanks!

Comment: thats confusing, in form1.cs you want access to a variable in MainApp.cs, so why go through the Helper class to get it? Why not just access it from MainApp.cs

Comment: So are you asking how to access the instance public variable in the MAIN_APP from the HELPER_CLASS_1?

Comment: well helper class actually contains DataTable, and the 'get_variable_i_want()' function is actually 'init_data_tables'. The function would create datatable columns, based on mothers class VARIABLE_I_WANT_TO_ACCESS.

Comment: Yes, Daryl, that's what I need to access

Answer (score 0):

It's a public and static variable. You should be able to access it. Use the complete path name